# Advanced WP Query and/or

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I'm trying to create an advanced, reusable query function.

I need to query by category OR a category + a tag.

I know how to do this with custom fields (meta queries) but how do I do it with simple categories and tags?

A pseudo SQL Query would be:

```
Select * from Posts where ( cat_id = 1 OR (cat_id = 5 AND tag_id = 6) )
```

The query could change to need to include a set of tags

```
Select * from Posts where ( cat_id = 1 OR ( cat_id = 5 AND tag_id = (5,6,7) ))
```

Currently I'm using wp_query and passing args, but I guess I could write a one-off query_posts if needed.

Here is a rough version of my custom query. I'm guessing I need to add another argument for my desired 'or' statement?

```
$args = array(
     'post_type'            => $postType, //assume 'post'
     'cat'                  => $cat_id, //currently a single id
     'orderby'              => 'date',
     'post_status'          => 'publish',
    );
```

I got some help from [Best practice for multiple queries on page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51267/best-practice-for-multiple-queries-on-page)

So now I need to add a tax_query, but here is where my query fails

```
$taxQuery = array(
       'relation' => 'AND',  //Is this "And" my original query, or just "and" these two parameters?            
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => 5
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(5,6,7)
                )
        );
```

My updated WP_query would be :

```
$args = array(
     'post_type'            => $postType, //assume 'post'
     'cat'                  => $cat_id, //currently a single id
     'tax_query'            => $taxQuery,
     'orderby'              => 'date',
     'post_status'          => 'publish',
    );
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: and/or what? ---------

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking but as written that is going to be wrong.  `tax_query` is an array of arrays but you have an array of array of arrays. You create the third array when you put `$taxQuery` into `array($taxQuery)`. This should be more correct:

```
$args = array(
     'post_type'            => $postType, //assume 'post'
     'cat'                  => $cat_id, //currently a single id
     'tax_query'            => $taxQuery,
     'orderby'              => 'date',
     'post_status'          => 'publish',
);
```

With your version, if you `var_dump` the query you can see 0=1 in the SQL which reflects the broken `tax_query`, and if you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you can see `Notice`s.

Unfortunately, you can't do a complicated query like this one...

```
Select * from Posts where ( cat_id = 1 OR ( cat_id = 5 AND tag_id = (5,6,7) ))
```

... with `WP_Query`. The nested conditions in the `WHERE` are too complex for `WP_Query`.

You have several options:

1. Write the SQL yourself
2. Let `WP_Query` do part of the work and alter, at the very least, the
   `WHERE` clause with `posts_where`
3. Run several queries to grab the data.

The latter would look something like:

```
$post_ids = new WP_Query(array(
  // query for one post type
  'fields' => 'ids',
  // other parameters
));

$post_ids_2 = new WP_Query(array(
  // query for the others
  'fields' => 'ids',
  // other parameters
));
// join them
$post_ids = $post_ids->posts + $post_ids_2->posts;
$posts_qry = new WP_Query(array('post__in'=> $posts_ids));
```

That is [taken from another answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99619/21376) so none of the parameter are right for you but that should give you idea. That is by far the easiest solution but also the least efficient.

Comment: Thanks - you are correct - I had another function that was taking an array of arrays for an advanced date filter. Still, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Nate : see the edit

Answer (score 1):

One way to do the AND / OR nested query, which worked for me, is to simply pass an array of values. I believe it implicitly uses the list as an OR via the IN(a,b...) MySQL syntax.

Here's an example that I was able to use for a taxonomy query:

```
// ... Other query params in $query

$query['tax_query'] = ['relation' => 'AND'];

$query['tax_query'][] =[[   'taxonomy' => 'field_a',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => ['a','b','c']]; // this is the "OR"


$query['tax_query'][] =[[   'taxonomy' => 'field_b',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => ['d','e','f']]; // this is the "OR"


$get_posts = new WP_Query;
$posts = $get_posts->query($query);
```

This in essence generates a query such as:

```
field_a IN('a','b','c') AND field_b IN('d','e','f')
```